# Switching licenses between Customer Community and Customer Community Plus

Tags: community, licenses, customer-community

During our first tests with Salesforce Communities we figured out, that users can't be switched from Partner Community License (PCL) to a Customer Community License (CCL).

This is also documented here by Salesforce.com:
[image: Community License Switching]

Now, that Salesforce.com introduced the Customer Community Plus License (CCPL), **we would like to know if switching back-and-forth between CCPL and CCL on a user record is possible**. If yes, this would enable us to have a mix of both licenses inside the system, and assign it to users based on demand for functionality.

Comment: I don't have a definite answer hence the comment, but I would expect you to be able to switch from CCL to CCPL, but not go back. In general, Salesforce allows you to add features, but not remove it. For example, you can't go from Chatter Plus to Chatter.

Comment: @DanielHoechst : Yes and no, I can also switch our users between Salesforce license and Salesforce Platform back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

The above does not seem to be the case nor as simple as implied. When moving from a customer community user license to a customer community plus user it is not as simple as changing the user license and profile on the user object. 
It would appear that you have to migrate the users ( create the new user as a customer community plus license, then deactivate the old one ).

Answer (score 0):

You can switch from CCL to CCPL but you can't switch from CCPL to CCL.
Salesforce do not allow this.

Comment: You should have included the link to the SF Documentation and noted that this only came in recently - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_upgrade_licenses.htm&type=0 https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_license_upgrade_eligible.htm&type=0&language=en_US